# Replace item by index in sequence

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I guess this should be really stupid, but I'm currently doing it this way:

```
array = [[[array rac_sequence] map:^id(id value) {
    return [array indexOfObject:value] == indexToChange ? newValue : value;
}] array];
```

But I'm sure there should be a better why to accomplish this, right?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're both starting and ending with an array, I'd just turn it into a mutable array and mutate it that way.

Comment: so you wouldn't avoid creating an `[array mutableCopy]` variable?